# Unable to Pass Thai language as a parameter in JMeter

Tags: parameters, jmeter

In User defined Variable I stored a variable with Value in ThaiLanguage(Eg:ภาษาไทย). While passing variable in a request it is passing like ????????. 
I also tried to store in CSV with encoding type as unicode and with the help of CSV Data set Config with no file encoding type and provided a variable name. While Passing the variable provided in CSV data set config in a request it is passing like ÿþ 2)2D".
Please provide solution to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

In a HTTP Sampler, I just added the Content encoding type as UTF-8 and it worked like a charm for me.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVAmn.png)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue using the latest stable [JMeter 5.2.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-2-1-released-td5728641.html) neither for User Defined Variables nor for CSV Data Set Config approaches:

[image]

Make sure that:

1. [`file.encoding` system property](https://www.baeldung.com/java-char-encoding) is set to `UTF-8`
2. `csvdataset.file.encoding_list` JMeter property is set to or contains `UTF-8`
3. `sampleresult.default.encoding` JMeter property is set to `UTF-8`
4. Your CSV file is stored as UTF-8 (not ANSI or whatever is the default encoding in your OS)

   [image]

Check out [JMeter Properties Reference](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html) and [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/) to learn more about different JMeter properties types and ways of setting and overriding them.